# How can i add Anaconda Prompt to VScode terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

i'm trying to add anaconda prompt to vscode terminal.

i googled it, but i found that it's not possible method cuz

terminal.integrated.shell.windows

terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows

is now unavailable on settings.

is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that it can't be realized at present.The Python extension automatically detects existing conda environments provided that the environment contains a Python interpreter. Although the Python extension for VS Code doesn't currently have direct integration with conda environment.yml files, VS Code itself is a great YAML editor.

Answer (score 0):

The most I could think of is setting Conda as your interpreter (in the Command  Palette type in Python Interpreter, select it, and click on the one that says "conda"). That should allow you to run your code in the conda enviornment.